# Last time to send Bitcoin to Trezor before fork

Tags: blockchain-fork, bitcoin-gold

What's the last safest time I can send bitcoins to my trezor for the upcoming bicoin gold fork? I'm asking because I want to maximise the benefit from price fluctuation on my exchange since I'm trading.

Thankyou

Comment: https://blog.trezor.io/trezor-statement-on-bitcoin-gold-fork-78cebc0532c7

Answer (score 1):

Bitcoin Gold will fork at block 491407, which means that the first Bitcoin Gold block will be at height 491407. So as long as your transaction confirms before block 491407, your transaction will exist on both blockchains.